# How to Rename multiple images with same name of the files in other folder?

Tags: windows-7, images, rename, bulk

I have two folders with the following images

> 1. Original images
>
>    - Customer-Engagement-Small
>    - engineer
>    - first-aid-kit
> 2. Optimized images
>
>    - Customer-Engagement-Small_70e76dfedeadb41a97636ca7006a5953
>    - engineer_6bab3639c8cde4ef2c7ab4b8eafb888b
>    - first-aid-kit_bd2d3ee1bb7a5632c66c4f269409e9ab

This is a sample. But I have thousands of files in these folder

My current workflow is:

1. Click on an image
2. Press <kbd>F2</kbd>
3. Copy file name and paste to other files

It takes so much time. Is there a shorter way?
How do I rename these folder images to first ones.

Note: All the files in same order

Comment: Welcome to Superuser, from what it looks like all your files have a 32 characters long suffix. Together with the underline it is 33. Wouldn't a program or script which just removes the last 33 characters fulfill your needs? Or are there other name changes which do not fit into this pattern?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this code to rename your optimized images by deleting everything that's after the underline "_" (if your files don't have two underlines).

```
@echo off
for /F "delims=" %%I in ('dir /A-D /B *_* 2^>nul') do (
    for /F "tokens=1 delims=_ " %%J in ("%%~nI") do ren "%%I" "%%J%%~xI"
)
```

Put this code in a text editor and save it as anyname.bat in the Optimized images folder and run it. Make a copy of your folder first.

Comment: Thanks For Your Solution I think this one is correct. but i need little bit change in this code... Check the name from behind and remove texts after ("_").. Bcoz some file name contain two underlines so i need to remove from backward any suggests please..

Answer (score 1):

I do it using these steps:

1. Create list of source files using command `Dir /on /b > source.txt`
2. Create list of target file names using command `Dir /on /b > Target.txt`
3. Open MS excel
4. Open `Source.txt` and copy all names in column `B` of MS Excel sheet.
5. Open `Target.txt` and copy all names in column `C` of MS Excel sheet.
6. Fill column `A` with `DOS` command `REN`.
7. Copy values of all three columns and paste in `Notepad` and save the file with extension `.bat`.
8. Execute this batch file in source folder.

[image]

**In order to get it done successfully, number of file and file order must match.**

Comment: Using Excel to simulate "Rectangle Editing"... interesting solution! Only problem is that it isn't recursive.

Comment: @TNierath Thanks for pointing that out. However, we can make it work for sub-folders as well. That would need additional steps of `find and replace` and possibly `macro` in `Notepad++`. To get path of all sub-folders `Dir /s /on /b` command can be used.

Answer (score 1):

Check out https://www.howtogeek.com/111859/how-to-batch-rename-files-in-windows-4-ways-to-rename-multiple-files/

"Bulk Rename Utility" or "Advanced Renamer" should satisfy your needs.